# If I apply "float: left;" to a inner div, why does it affect the background color of it's parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple design where I have 4 small boxes lined up on top of one another each with the same dimensions. However, when I try to apply "float: left" to the boxes, the background color of it's parent div goes away. Why is this? What does it have to do with the background color? I would just like my background color to remain the same.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mush5ecc/

My html code:

```
<div id="careers">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 id="careers_title">Careers</h2>

    <div id="four_grids">
        <div id="top_left" class="grid"></div>
        <div id="top_right" class="grid"></div>
        <div id="bottom_left" class="grid"></div>
        <div id="bottom_right" class="grid"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
  #careers {
    background-color: orange;
  }

 .container { 
    width: 1026px; 
    margin: auto;
  }

  #careers_title {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 67px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }

  .grid {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left; /* COMMENT FLOAT TO SEE WHAT HAPPENS */
   }


   #top_left {
     background-color: blue;
   }


  #top_right {
    background-color: green;
  }


  #bottom_left {
    background-color: red;
  }


  #bottom_right {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply `overflow: hidden` to `<div id="four_grids">`.

See [here](http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php) for further details on this behaviour.

Comment: Got it! Why did I need to do that in the first place? How does that work

Comment: @Pot-Nut I was just under the impression that if you have a inner div within the parent and it's parent div is set by default to height auto, that this problem would not occur.

Comment: Only if the parent `<div>` is floated too. As far as I'm aware the parent would require an explicit height too. You can either float the parent, add an extra `<div>` in the parent with `clear: both` on it, or simply use `overflow: hidden` on the parent (my preferred choice).

Comment: Or instead of using `float: left`, try using `display: inline-block` and setting your desired width. This would prevent the need for additional styles on the parent in the first place.

Comment: @Pot-Nut this is by far the most complicated part of CSS to understand to me haha!

Comment: It all comes with time! =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure of what your goal is, but I added the following css and I think this may be what you are looking for.

```
#four_grids {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This would only be necessary if the question specified elements may need to stretch outside of the `<div id="four_grids">` container. Setting `overflow: hidden` is sufficient for the askers case.